# URL rewriting with a hash

Tags: hash, url-rewriting

So, I am new to url rewriting, and was wondering if it is possible to rewrite the url when a hash comes into play. For instance, I have the following URL:

```
http://testdomain.com/#/test.php
```

Is there a way to rewrite this to:

```
http://testdomain.com/index.php?url=test.php
```

I am not sure whether the hash effectively makes this 'invisible' on the php side. I tried to capture the request URL this way, and it does not read anything from the hash on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading more up on this, I have found it not to be possible, as the hash is not sent to the server, and is client side only.