# Redirect to Flash section with UrlRewriter.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, urlrewriter.net

I'm using UrlRewriter.NET for URL Rewrite. But my site is made with flash. All flash sections load inside a Default.aspx. When a section is loaded the URL changes to, and can be accessed from **mysite.com/Default.aspx#SectionName**

My goal is to be able to access from just typing **mysite.com/SectionName**

So I use this inside my web.config:

```xml
<rewrite url="~/Quiniela" to="~/Default.aspx#/Quiniela"/>
```

And I get a 404 error.

If I use:

```xml
<rewrite url="~/Quiniela" to="~/Default.aspx"/>
```

I get a successful redirect.

So my question is ¿What values do I need to write inside the to="" parameter to achieve redirection to my flash section?

Comment: Is that extra slash after the # throwing you?  Should the to= be just ~/Default.aspx#Quiniela ?

Comment: I tried using to="~/Default.aspx#Quiniela" but it also gets a 404 error.

Comment: A quick search turned this up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7240212/url-rewriting-with-a-hash